# Voronoi Node Fracture Module for 2.8?

Tags: node-editor

Does anyone know if progress is being made on the Voronoi Fracture module for 2.8? Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it will attract speculation about unknown development targets

Comment: Just wondering, why would this question be off topic? Seems to be about a part of Blender that is very important to some of us.

Comment: Also, I just received this answer from another source, which might be very relevant to some people who are using 2.8: It's in latest beta 2.8 build. Works fine most of the time, but may cause blender to crash, so save often.
Edit - preferences - Tick 'Cell Fracture'
Then either search it under spacebar menu or select object, go to 'Object - Quick Effects - Cell Fracture'

Comment: Since most people here are not Blender developers no one can give you an accurate answer of when or if. Even the developers probably don't know themselves, so any post here would an opinion or speculation from our part at best